# Can I move a term of an infinite series before the summation sign?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have the infinite series
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_nh\big((k-n)T\big).
$$
Can I write
$$
a_kh(0)+\sum_{\substack{n=-\infty, \\n\neq k}}^{\infty}a_nh\big((k-n)T\big)  \quad ?
$$

Comment: Yes, this is always valid.

Comment: Yes. This doesnt affect the convergence (or divergence) of the series.

Comment: Just out of interest, is $h$ a function? I'm curious to see what properties $h$ exhibits.

Comment: Yes. Any sensible definition of infinite summation should be linear and assign the value $c$ to each sequence $n \mapsto c\delta_{nk}$. Using this you can prove your claim.

Comment: You can always move a finite number of terms out, and rearrange them in any order. This is because there are no limits involved in manipulating a finite number of terms. The trouble only starts when you rearrange an infinite number of terms, because then the validity depends on whether that infinite number of terms has a valid sum (i.e. converges or not).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct. The first expression equals the latter.

Comment: Hi! But instead of $$a_kh(0)+\sum_{n=-\infty\\{n\neq k}}^{\infty}a_nh\big((k-n)T\big)$$can I also write $$a_kh(0)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nh\big((k-n)T\big)\quad ?$$

Comment: You can't just leave out all terms with $n<1$. Also, the term with $n=k$ is counted twice now. So no.